# Bubble chart data input in Python (dash_alternative_viz) with Highcharts

Tags: python, highcharts, plotly-dash

Last days I play around with Highcharts  in Python Dash with dash_alternative_viz library.

Link: https://github.com/plotly/dash-alternative-viz

I can create various charts, but I have major problem with creating Bubble chart. I do not know how to input data to this kind of chart. I tried many ways but as a result I get error or empty chart.

Like here below simple bar chart:
[image: figure1]

Does anybody used this package and somehow generated the Bubble chart, and can share source code so I can see how to deliver input in right format.

Thanks,
Albert

Comment: Any solutions? Let me knwo